# Opencart: Using Twig_Autoloader is deprecated since version 1.21. Use Composer instead

Tags: php, composer-php, twig, opencart

I have a question:

**I am running Opencart Version 3.0.3.2 on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine.**

When I execute an action in the **admin extension** that sends out emails with **PHPMailer** (current version), I get the following error:

```
Using Twig_Autoloader is deprecated since version 1.21. Use Composer instead.
```

Does anybody know, how to solve this problem? Couldn't find any appropriate solution by google.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Maybe more current packages could resolve the problem? `twig/twig` in v1.21 is seven years old, and anywhere in the code you haven't shared yet you use a feature that is deprecated since then

Comment: Update Opencart, you're using an outdated release.